# Convert Maven Site Software Documentation to PDF

Tags: pdf, maven-2, maven-plugin, maven-pdf-plugin

I am currently working on a project written in Java and I am using Maven and the maven-site-plugin to generate a website containing all the relevant JavaDoc, reports, etc.  I am needing at the same time to be able to convert the same documentation into a readable, book-like format.  Are there any scripts or tools out there designed to take a website, and convert it into a reasonably formatted PDF or other style so that it can be easily given digitally or printed out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [maven-pdf-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pdf-plugin/) generates a PDF of the project documentation.

Two notes from the documentation to consider:

> **Note 1:** By default, the PDF plugin generates a PDF document which aggregates all your site documents. If you want to generate each site document individually, you need to add `-Daggregate=false` in the command line.
>
> **Note 2:** By default, the PDF plugin uses the FOP implementation. The plugin also supports the iText implementation, you just need to add `-Dimplementation=itext` in the command line.

You can actually specify the aggregate property in your POM (see example below).

This configuration will generate the PDF on each build that the `docs` profile is active (you could do it on every build, but it would be a bit slow for your typical development cycle:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>docs</id>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-pdf-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>pdf</id>
          <phase>site</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>pdf</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>
              ${project.reporting.outputDirectory}
            </outputDirectory>
            <aggregate>false</aggregate>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

You can activate the profile on the command line with `-P docs` or use an [activation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) configuration if you want to be finer-grained.

Comment: Only thing this plugin seems to be unable to do is include some of the more extensive maven generated reports, as you have to give it a list of every file to include, which would be a ton for things like JavaDoc and wouldn't work dynamically as code changes.

Comment: @FModa3 yes it is not ideal, but a workaround for that is to use something like the groovy plugin to process the files to generate the xsl